# Android How to scan a card color, number

Tags: android, android-ndk

Hi ever One I am recently working on android app in which i need to scan  **Card game card's number shape and symbol in android via camera** Can anyone suggest me the best way to solve this problem and give me some tutorial and links

1. I need to scan shape and color from a set of cards available example

10-spades j-hearts q-diamonds

i should identify all the symbols and colors of the card when i start scanning them.

1. Help me in giving solution for a single card when i start scanning a single card it should  identify the card shape, color and symbol